# R: Count the Number of Missing Years Per ID

Tags: r

I have this data frame in R:

```
my_data = data.frame( id = c(111,111,111,222,222,222,222, 333,333,333,333,444,444), year = c(2010,2011,2012, 2015, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2010,2012, 2013, 2014, 2021, 2022))

> my_data
    id year
1  111 2010
2  111 2011
3  111 2012
4  222 2015
5  222 2019
6  222 2020
7  222 2021
8  333 2010
9  333 2012
10 333 2013
11 333 2014
12 444 2021
13 444 2022
14 555 2010
```

**My Question:** I want to find out the number of id's that have "no missing years" and the number of id's that have "at least one missing year" - and then "count" the total number of missing years (e.g. for id = 222, count = 2019 - 2015 = 4)

I tried to do this with the following code:

```
library(dplyr)

my_data1 <- my_data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(year_diff = year - lag(year)) %>%
    filter(!is.na(year_diff)) %>%
    summarise(has_gap = any(year_diff > 1)) %>%
    right_join(my_data, by = "id")

# this is needed for id's with only 1 observation
my_data1 = my_data1 %>%
    mutate_all(~ifelse(is.na(.), "FALSE", .))
```

So far, the final output is in the desirable format:

```
# A tibble: 13 x 3
      id has_gap  year
   <dbl> <lgl>   <dbl>
 1   111 FALSE    2010
 2   111 FALSE    2011
 3   111 FALSE    2012
 4   222 TRUE     2015
 5   222 TRUE     2019
 6   222 TRUE     2020
 7   222 TRUE     2021
 8   333 TRUE     2010
 9   333 TRUE     2012
10   333 TRUE     2013
11   333 TRUE     2014
12   444 FALSE    2021
13   444 FALSE    2022
```

**I am not sure how to add a "count" column here that will count the number of missing years - can someone please show me how to do this?**

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want `my_data1 %>% distinct(id, has_gap) %>% summarise(count_no_missing = sum(!has_gap), count_at_least_one = sum(has_gap))`

Comment: `?rle`   The answer is always  `rle()`    .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to count the number of missing years per id, subtract the difference in the range of years from the length:

```r
my_data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(missing_years = diff(range(year)) - length(year) + 1)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>      id missing_years
#>   <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1   111             0
#> 2   222             3
#> 3   333             1
#> 4   444             0
```

Comment: I think your code can be converted into SQL like this?

Comment: SELECT id, (MAX(year) - MIN(year) + 1) - COUNT(year) AS missing_years
FROM my_data
GROUP BY id

Answer (score 2):

Playing with `diff`, `any` and `all`:

```r
my_data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(no_missing = all(diff(year) == 1),
         one_missing = any(diff(year) != 1),
         n_missing = sum(diff(year)[diff(year) != 1]))
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 13 × 5
# Groups:   id [4]
      id  year no_missing one_missing n_missing
   <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>      <lgl>           <dbl>
 1   111  2010 TRUE       FALSE               0
 2   111  2011 TRUE       FALSE               0
 3   111  2012 TRUE       FALSE               0
 4   222  2015 FALSE      TRUE                4
 5   222  2019 FALSE      TRUE                4
 6   222  2020 FALSE      TRUE                4
 7   222  2021 FALSE      TRUE                4
 8   333  2010 FALSE      TRUE                2
 9   333  2012 FALSE      TRUE                2
10   333  2013 FALSE      TRUE                2
11   333  2014 FALSE      TRUE                2
12   444  2021 TRUE       FALSE               0
13   444  2022 TRUE       FALSE               0
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
my_data1 %>% 
   distinct(id, has_gap) %>% 
   summarise(count_no_missing = sum(!has_gap), count_at_least_one = sum(has_gap))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  count_no_missing count_at_least_one
             <int>              <int>
1                2                  2
```

---

Or if we need

```
my_data %>%
   reframe(no_missing = length(setdiff(min(year):max(year), year)), .by = id)
```

-output

```
   id no_missing
1 111          0
2 222          3
3 333          1
4 444          0
```

Answer (score 1):

Also showing missing years

```
my_data %>% 
  summarize(Missing = list(seq(min(year), max(year))), 
            Missing = list(unlist(Missing)[which(!(unlist(Missing) %in% year))]),
            n_missing = lengths(Missing), .by = id)
   id          Missing n_missing
1 111                          0
2 222 2016, 2017, 2018         3
3 333             2011         1
4 444                          0
```